# different name for dynamically generated text field in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is  a jquery to generate dynamic input text field in html. 
TO give different name to each text field, 'num ' is incremented .
I even try  ".attr('name', 'device' + num);"... But its not working .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var num=0;
        num++;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");

**var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" name=\"' + num + '\" />");**

        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fName);

        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });

});
```

if 3 new text fields are generated now,
how can i add the value in each text field onkeyup

Answer (score 3):

You override the `num` on each click, and messed up the string notations.
Put the `num` declartion outside the callback:

```
var num=0;
$("#add").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
    num++;
    $('<input type="text" class="fieldname" name="' + num + '" />');
```

A tip of the day, in javascript you can use `'` and `"` for strings notations, you them both and you won't need to escape the other notation.

Comment: By declaring num outside the function & changing the below line solved  the problem
    var fName = ($('<input type="text"  name="' + num + '" />'));

Comment: how can i add the value in each text field onkeyup

Comment: @Prads, I didn't understand what you asked.

Comment: i managed to do this in php ... Is there a way to sum the value in each dynamically generated text field (onkeyup event).

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code, you mess with single and double quotes...

Should be something like this

```
var fName = $('<input type="text" class="fieldname" name="' + num + '" />');
```

OR:

```
var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" name=\"" + num + "\" />");
```